# STU-model for Black holes

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, terminology, supergravity, duality

In string theory in the realm of black holes, what does the acronym [STU](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=stu+black+holes) stands for when we talk about the STU model?

Comment: S, T and U dualities

Answer (score 1):

Is a particular case of $\mathcal N=2$, $D=4$ Supergravity with Kalher manifold:

$$\left( \frac{SU(1,1)}{U(1)} \right)^3$$

The three complex scalars of the models are usually dubbed S,T,U.